# LVDT Simulation in Spice

Tags: transformer, simulation, inductance, spice

I have a two-coil LVDT where the position of the rod relates to a level of vacuum.

I excited the LVDT with a 2V ptp AC sine wave and measured the Vrms in (700.6V per Picoscope) and Vrms out to calculate the coupling ratio k. The value of k varies depending on the vacuum with a value of 0.498 when there is no vacuum.

I also measured the resistance and inductance of the two coils with no vacuum.

Here is the spice circuit. I have set the coupling ratio to 1.0 because if I set it to 0.498 the output Vrms is very small. This made me think that when using the coupling ratio in Spice I need to make the inductance of both coils the same. Is that right?

The simulated input waveform is a 2V ptp AC sine wave. With this simulation I get an output with Vrms of 322mV which gives a k value of 0.467. I expected to get a value of 0.498. The simulated value of 0.467 corresponds to more than 15inHg of vacuum which is the other end of the scale for this LVDT.

Do I have a flaw in my approach?

Is there a way to improve the accuracy of the simulation?

Thanks!

UPDATE - I have found that if I change the load from 500 Ohms to 1.6k then I can get a matching output. But what does this mean? Am I making the simulation meaningless or am I matching the load of my scope?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a part number or schematic diagram for the LVDT?  I'm thinking there's a good chance that its a 3-coil LVDT that's wired internally to bring out the sum of the secondary coil voltages.

Comment: @TimWescott it's an old part from the 1970s. It definitely has two coils. What makes you wary of that?

Comment: Set a lower maximum timestep, your sine waves are not very sinusoidal.

Comment: As a good starting point, if you need your waveforms to have good time resolution, start with a timestep of 1000x-10000x smaller than the period of interest (as suggested by @SpehroPefhany). You frequency is 1 kHz => T=1 ms => timestep=max(1 us ... 0.1 us). There may also be settings altering the displayed waveform (e.g. in LTspice there's `.opt plotwinsize=0` which disables waveform compression).

Comment: Thanks. I increased the resolution. Now I get a k of 0.467, still higher than expected

Comment: @Andy just that there seems to be every possible way of making an LVDT; I've been burned myself by making assumptions about what's inside the case based on the wires coming out of it.